# How to use Control+arrow to switch vim tabs in screen?

Tags: vim, screen

I have configured vim to use the control+arrow to switch tabs by adding following lines in .vimrc:

```
map <F7> :tabp<cr>
map <F8> :tabn<cr>
map <C-up> :tabr<cr>
map <C-down> :tabl<cr>
map <C-left> :tabp<cr>
map <C-right> :tabn<cr>
```

In *screen*, the `<F7>` and `<F8>` works, but the control+arrows do not...

Any idea why? And how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you on? Some keys are consumed by the OS before reaching applications. For instance in macOS, Ctrl-{left,right} are consumed by the OS for Mission Control.

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks for the comment. It's Centos 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it will work, but you could try to include this code inside your `vimrc`:

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
    sil! exe "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
    sil! exe "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
    sil! exe "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
    sil! exe "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
endif
```

I copied it from [here](https://superuser.com/a/402084/747860).

If you use tmux, you may also need to enable the option `xterm-keys` inside your tmux config file (`~/.tmux.conf`):

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
```

It's described in `man tmux`:

```
 xterm-keys [on | off]
         If this option is set, tmux will generate xterm(1) -style function key sequences; these have a
         number included to indicate modifiers such as Shift, Alt or Ctrl.  The default is off.
```

I don't know what the equivalent for `screen` is.

---

It's also possible that something (window manager, terminal multiplexer, terminal emulator) is intercepting `<C-left>` before Vim.

To rule out this possibility, you could try to insert `<C-left>` literally in a Vim buffer by typing `C-v C-left`, in insert mode, and see what it displays. On my machine, it displays `^[[1;5D`, so I know that nothing intercepts `<C-left>`.

If nothing is displayed, then you will have to find which software is intercepting `<C-left>` and remove the key binding in its configuration.

Comment: Thanks. The `if` part in .vimrc works. Could you please explain a bit how?

Comment: @dlz I've edited the answer to provide more information. Let me know if something is wrong or unclear, and I'll try to edit further.

Comment: thanks. I understand it much better now. Just one more question: by using character x, vim should treat S- and C- the same?

Comment: @dlz I think that `x` allows you to use a single line to handle both modifiers during your setup of the keys. However, there shouldn't be any confusion for Vim, because when you hit your modified arrow keys, they all produce different keycodes.

Comment: @dlz The ending digit should be different. You can make some tests on your machine, and type `C-v S-up` and `C-v C-up` in insert mode and you should see a difference.

Comment: yes. They are different. But how does it know `^[[1;2C` is corresponding to S-left instead of C-left?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148769/discussion-between-dlz-and-user852573).